# power modulus operations on an byte array

Tags: arrays, c, math, byte, modulo

How can I apply a power modulus to a byte array?

Example:

```
a = 0x449F
b = 0x0002
c = 0xffff

a^b % c = 0xed25
```

Now lets put this into an array

```c
uint8_t a[] = { 0x44, 0x9F };
uint8_t b[] = { 0x00, 0x02 };
uint8_t c[] = { 0xff, 0xff };
```

What formula can I use to get 0xed in this instance?

For reference, the issue I'm having is in C and my array is 32 bytes.

Comment: Edit the question to explain what the function `pow`. Also, in C, you should use a different name for it. `pow` is already used for a standard C routine.

Comment: If your source numbers are 32 bytes wide, you need a bigint library.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Edited

Comment: You are performing [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation)

Comment: There is a library listed there you could use.

Comment: The `gmp` library has some functions: https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Exponentiation

Comment: Thank you. I just saw the gmp library. Much appreciated.

Comment: on most modern computers little endian is used: `uint8_t a[] = { 0x9F, 0x44 };`